# List of tuples to dictionary not working as expected

Tags: python, dictionary

For some reason my small small brain is having problems with this, I have a list of tuples `list = [('name:john','age:25','location:brazil'),('name:terry','age:32','location:acme')]`. Im trying to move these values into a dictionary for parsing later. I have made a few attempts, below the latest of these and im not getting all results into the dict, the dict ends up with the last value iterated (its recreating the dict each time).

```
people = {}

list = [('name:john','age:25','location:brazil'),('name:terry','age:32','location:acme')]

for value in list:
        people = {'person': [dict(item.split(":",1) for item in value)]}
```

Comment: What do you want it looking like? From this code, it isn't clear.

Comment: It's because you're overriding `people` on each iteration. But it's not clear what you want to happen though. See [ask] and [mcve] for details on how to ask a good question.

Comment: It seems strange to store key-value pairs as a single string.

Comment: Appologies, i was expecting a nested dict like so `{person:{name:john,age:25,location:etc}}`. Although the top level is not required, just a dict with `{name:john,age:25,location:etc}` would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one too:

```
inlist = [('name:john','age:25','location:brazil'),('name:terry','age:32','location:acme')]
d = []

for tup in inlist:
    tempDict = {}
    for elem in tup:
        elem = elem.split(":")
        tempDict.update({elem[0]:elem[1]})
    d.append({'person':tempDict})

print(d)
```

Output:

```
[{'person': {'location': 'brazil', 'name': 'john', 'age': '25'}}, {'person': {'location': 'acme', 'name': 'terry', 'age': '32'}}]
```

If you want a dictionary with a key `person` and values the dictionaries with the people's info, then replace `d.append({'person':tempDict})` with `d.append(tempDict)` and add `d = {'person':d}` right before printing.

Output:

```
{'person': [{'location': 'brazil', 'name': 'john', 'age': '25'}, {'location': 'acme', 'name': 'terry', 'age': '32'}]}
```

Comment: arr this looks to be what im trying to do and as its not a comprension I can read it more clearly. Thank you, I will try this on some live data

Comment: @iNoob you're welcome. Notify me if you have any issues with this code.

Comment: This does work as suggested, but I just noticed im getting multiple `person` dicts. The original intent was one `person` dict with all said persons in it.

Comment: I may just forego the person top level altogether

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
l = [('name:john','age:25','location:brazil'),('person:terry','age:32','location:acme')]
people = [{c:d for c, d in [i.split(':') for i in a]} for a in l]
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'john', 'age': '25', 'location': 'brazil'}, {'person': 'terry', 'age': '32', 'location': 'acme'}]
```

Comment: @ABDULNIYASPM accidentally added `itertools`. Removed now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try not to call your list *list*. This name is protected in python and used usually to get a list out of iterators or ranges etc.
I would make a list of people first and then append each person to the people list as separate dictionary as follows:

```
people = []

my_list = [('name:john','age:25','location:brazil'),('person:terry','age:32','location:acme')]

for tup in my_list:
    person = {}
    for item in tup:
        splitted = item.split(':')
        person.update({splitted[0]:splitted[1]})
    people.append(person)
```

The output then would be this:

```
[{'age': '25', 'location': 'brazil', 'name': 'john'},
 {'age': '32', 'location': 'acme', 'person': 'terry'}]
```

Comment: yeah, it was only for illustration purposes. but i'll refrain from doing so even for illustration purposes.